# Daniell approach to $\int \sigma \mbox{ } d\mu \geq 0$ clearification

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, integration

Can someone help me clarify the following proof.

**Theorem:** If $\sigma \in C_0$ and $\sigma \geq 0$ a.e.$(\mu)$, then $\int \sigma \mbox{ } d\mu \geq 0$

**Proof:** The inequality is equivalent to proving that if $\varepsilon >0$ is given, then $\int \sigma \mbox{ } d\mu \geq -2\varepsilon$

Let $E$ be the null set on which $\sigma(x) < 0$, and let $\{\tau_n\}$ be a nonnegative, nondecreasing sequence of elementary functions which diverge on $E$, and whose $\mu$-integrals are bounded by 1.

Form the sequence $\omega_n = (\sigma^{-} - \varepsilon \tau_n)^{+}$ of elementary functions. Since $\varepsilon \geq 0$ on $\Omega$ and $\sigma^-=0$ on $\Omega-E$,

it follows that, for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $\omega_n(x) = 0$ if $x \in \Omega-E \mbox{     }$     [1]

If $x \in E$, the sequence $-\varepsilon\tau_n(x) \downarrow -\infty$, from which it follows that $(\sigma^{-} - \varepsilon \tau_n) \downarrow -\infty$, therefore

[2] $\omega_n(x) = (\sigma^{-}(x) - \varepsilon \tau_n(x))^{+}\downarrow 0$ if $x \in E$

From the continuity of the integral and [1] and [2] we have:$\int\omega_n \mbox{ } \downarrow 0$

hence:

${\color{magenta} {\int\sigma\mbox{ } = \int \sigma^+\mbox{ }d\mu - \int \sigma^-\mbox d\mu = { -\varepsilon\int \tau_n d\mu - \int(\sigma^- -\varepsilon\tau_n)d\mu}}}$

since $\int \tau_n \mbox{ }d\mu \leq 1$ we have:

$\int \sigma \geq -\varepsilon - \int(\sigma^- -\varepsilon\tau_n)d\mu \geq -\varepsilon - \int\omega_n \mbox { }d\mu \geq -2\varepsilon$

$\blacksquare$

In the magenta part, I don't see how the positive and negative parts transformed into those respective integrals.

Basically how does $\int \sigma^+\mbox{ }d\mu$ become $-\varepsilon\int \tau_n d\mu$ and $\int \sigma^-\mbox d\mu$ become $\int(\sigma^- -\varepsilon\tau_n)d\mu$ ?

Comment: They don't. The last should have been a $\geqslant$.